# Java: How to write "Arabic" in properties file?

Tags: java, properties, struts2, resourcebundle

I want to write "Arabic" in the message resource bundle (properties) file but when I try to save it I get this error:

"Save couldn't be completed
Some characters cannot be mapped using "ISO-85591-1" character encoding. Either change encoding or remove the character ..."

Can anyone guide please?

I want to write:

global.username = اسم المستخدم

How should I write the Arabic of "username" in properties file? So, that internationalization works..

BR
SC

Answer (score 8, accepted):

http://sourceforge.net/projects/eclipse-rbe/

You can use the above plugin for eclipse IDE to make the Unicode conversion for you.

Comment: Thanks. Will this plugin will work with IBM RAD? And can I write and save "Arabic" in it... BR SC

Answer (score 5):

As described in the class reference for "Properties"

> The load(Reader) / store(Writer, String) methods load and store properties from and to 
>   a character based stream in a simple line-oriented format specified below. 
>   The load(InputStream) / store(OutputStream, String) methods work the same way as the
>    load(Reader)/store(Writer, String) pair, except the input/output stream is encoded in 
>   ISO 8859-1 character encoding. Characters that cannot be directly represented in this 
>   encoding can be written using Unicode escapes ; only a single 'u' character is allowed 
>   in an escape sequence. The native2ascii tool can be used to convert property files to 
>   and from other character encodings.

Answer (score 4):

Properties-based resource bundles must be encoded in ISO-8859-1 to use the default loading mechanism, but I have successfully used this code to allow the properties files to be encoded in UTF-8:

```
private static class ResourceControl extends ResourceBundle.Control {
    @Override
    public ResourceBundle newBundle(String baseName, Locale locale,
            String format, ClassLoader loader, boolean reload)
            throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException,
            IOException {
        String bundlename = toBundleName(baseName, locale);
        String resName = toResourceName(bundlename, "properties");
        InputStream stream = loader.getResourceAsStream(resName);
        return new PropertyResourceBundle(new InputStreamReader(stream,
                "UTF-8"));
    }

}
```

Then of course you have to change the encoding of the file itself to UTF-8 in your IDE, and can use it like this:

```
ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle(
    "package.Bundle", new ResourceControl());
```

Comment: Thanks but I am talking about editor which can save the text written in Arabic.

Comment: @SmoothCriminel: and I'm telling you that the editor is not the main problem: any decent text editor will allow you to choose the encoding (as the error message tells you). But that won't help you one bit when the MessageBundle class insists on interpreting the file as ISO-8859-1

Answer (score 1):

`new String(ret.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");` worked for me.
property file saved in ISO-8859-1 Encodiing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Eclipse, you can choose "Window-->Preferences" and then filter on "content types".  Then you should be able to set the default encoding.  There's a screen shot showing this at the top of [this post](http://www.techhui.com/profiles/blogs/localization-in-gwt-using).

Comment: And how is this exactly going to help?

Comment: This is how I set the encoding for the properties file when I encountered the same error message while trying to do something similar.

Comment: I changed encode to UTF-8, at least now it's not showing Unicode but still not proper one which shows in notepad

Comment: Eclipse: ÙÙ ÙØªÙ Ø§ÙØ¹Ø«ÙØ± Ø¹ÙÙ Ø§ÙØ³Ø¬Ù.
Notepad: لم يتم العثور على السجل.

Comment: Both place UTF-8 there

Answer (score 0):

This is mainly an editor configuration issue. If you're working in Windows, you can edit the text in an editor that supports UTF-8. Notepad or Eclipse built-in editor should be more than enough, provided you've saved file as UTF-8. In Linux, I've used gedit and emacs successfully. In Notepad, you can do this by clicking 'Save As' button and choosing 'UTF-8' encoding. Other editors should have similar feature. Some editors might require font change in order to display letters correctly, but it seems that you don't have this issue.

Having said that, there are other steps to consider when performing i18n for arabic. You can find some useful links below. Make sure to use native2ascii on properties file before using it otherwise it might not work. I spent a lot of time until I figured this one out.

[Tomcat webapps](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?33594-Tomcat-UTF-8-encoding-problem)

[Using nativ2ascii with properties files](http://www.coderanch.com/t/328839/java/java/reading-Arabic-properties-file)

Answer (score 0):

Besides native2ascii tool mentioned in other answers there is a java Open Source library that can provide conversion functionality to be used in code

Library MgntUtils has a Utility that converts Strings in any language (including special characters and emojis to unicode sequence and vise versa:

```
result = "Hello World";
result = StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder.encodeStringToUnicodeSequence(result);
System.out.println(result);
result = StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder.decodeUnicodeSequenceToString(result);
System.out.println(result);
```

The output of this code is:

```
\u0048\u0065\u006c\u006c\u006f\u0020\u0057\u006f\u0072\u006c\u0064
Hello World
```

The library can be found at [Maven Central](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.michaelgantman/MgntUtils/1.5.0.4/jar) or at [Github](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt) It comes as maven artifact and with sources and javadoc

Here is javadoc for the class [StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/utils/StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder.html)