# Unable to see arabic language in properties file

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am trying to implement multiple language in my project using Spring MVC tag. 
In the properties file i'm unable to see the arabic language. I'm getting like this.. Can anyone please help me to fix this...Thanks in advance...

```
label.login.heading=\u062A\u0633\u062C\u064A\u0644 \u0627\u0644\u062F\u062E\u0648\u0644
label.login.username=\u0627\u0633\u0645 \u0627\u0627\u0644\u0645\u0633\u062A\u062E\u062F\u0645
```

Comment: whats the URL of your landing page? Did you try appending `?locale=ar` to it (assuming it is working for other pages)?

Comment: http://localhost:8094/MyApp/ This is the url of the landing page. On clicking Arabic it goes to http://localhost:8094/MyApp/?locale=ar

Comment: Does a request to `localhost:8094/MyApp` go to a Spring MVC controller, or doess it go directly to welcome.jsp? If the latter, then make sure it's the former.

Comment: Does it work for another language? Can we see the spring mvc config used, where are the properties files located?

Comment: which IDE are you using to view the properties file? Are you using eclipse

Comment: @awsome yes i'm using Eclipse IDE..

Comment: then this question would probably answer your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4648513/java-how-to-write-arabic-in-properties-file

Comment: I changed it to UTF-8. Not at least it's not showing Unicode, but not proper Arab also. Compared with Notepad++ which has also UTF-8.
Eclipse: ÙÙ ÙØªÙ Ø§ÙØ¹Ø«ÙØ± Ø¹ÙÙ Ø§ÙØ³Ø¬Ù. Notepad: لم يتم العثور على السجل.